# Find all bases with given matricies of linear function between bases.

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Consider a linear mapping $\phi:\mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ given by the formula $\phi(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})=(3x_{1}+7x_{2}+4x_{3},x_{1}+2x_{2}+x_{3})$. Find all bases $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, such that $M(\phi)_{A}^{B}=\begin{matrix} 2& 2 & 1 \\ 1& 1 & 0\end{matrix}$.

How should I do this exercise? Which method should I use? The method of matrix multiplication and passing form one basis to another is a little bit complicated. Should I say that A consists of vectors $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$, $(x_{4},x_{5},x_{6})$, $(x_{7},x_{8},x_{9})$, B consists of $(x_{10},x_{11})$, $(x_{12},x_{13})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see here there are a lot of variables to solve. So you can start of solving this using the standard basis, but, assuming only 2 of them and keeping the 3rd basis as a variable.

$$
A=\{{u,(0,1,0),(0,0,1)}\}
$$
$$
B=\{{v_1,v_2}\}
$$

I chose the above two and kept u as variable only because of convenience. But remember to assume basis for only $R^3$ and not $R^2$.

Now, according to the matrix, we know the following

$$
\phi(u)=2v_1 + v_2 
$$
$$ 
\phi(0,1,0)=2v_1+v_2
$$
$$
\phi(0,0,1)=v_1
$$

but now according to the definition of phi we have

$$
\phi(0,1,0)=(7,2)
$$
$$
\phi(0,0,1)=(4,1)
$$

comparing it with the previous set of equations we have

$$
v_1=(4,1)
$$
$$
v_2=(-1,0)
$$

Now placing it back into (1) we have,

$$
\phi(u)=(7,2)
$$

when you solve the above equations considering $u=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ ,you will see that u belongs to the space spanned by the vector $(1,0,1)$.

I will take this as u(if you want you can take any real multiple of the above vector as u a there are no restrictions placed on how the basis vectors should be).

Hurrah!!

You have now found out A and B.

Comment: Hi there, please type the important mathematical content with Mathjax.  You can get started [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/80734), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: thanks a lot @Calvin Khor. Looks very different and much better now.

Comment: Glad to help and glad it has improved! A suggestion- $x1$ `x1` vs $x_1$`x_1`

Comment: Thanks a lot mathmyth for your answer. That was very helpful.

Comment: Happy to help .Thanks again @Calvin Khor.